# java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size, Fix works but issue cannot be reproduced

Tags: java, jce

My application (running on glassfish) accesses google spreadsheet to retrieve certain information, I use the 
google-api-client to perform OAuth and get the access to the spreadsheets.

More details on OAuth and Spreadsheet API can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Following is the snippet of code which gets the AuthenticatedService

```
    public SpreadsheetService getAuthenticatedService() {

            SpreadsheetService service =
                    new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

            try {

                //Generating a token every time, for the current requirements this is fine.
                JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
                HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
                String filePath = RW_SW_P_12_KEY;
                String keyFilePath = new File(this.getClass().getResource(filePath).toURI()).getAbsolutePath();
                GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                        .setTransport(httpTransport)
                        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                        .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountEmail)
                        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(keyFilePath))
                        .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"))
                        .setServiceAccountUser(userName)
                        .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                        .build();

                credential.setExpiresInSeconds(3600L);
                service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
                service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                LOGGER.error(ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
                Throwables.propagate(ioe);
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException se) {
                LOGGER.error(se.getMessage(), se);
                Throwables.propagate(se);
            } catch (URISyntaxException use) {
                LOGGER.error(use.getMessage(), use);
                Throwables.propagate(use);
            }

            return service;
        }
```

However I ran into the following error:

```
    exception unwrapping private key - java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
        java.io.IOException: exception unwrapping private key - java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.unwrapKey(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
        at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:82)
        at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:115)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(GoogleCredential.java:670)
        at com.bwc.stratus.steelwedge.GSpreadSheetServiceImpl.getAuthenticatedService(GSpreadSheetServiceImpl.java:89)
```

I found a work around and that worked

http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-install-java-cryptography.html

However, when I tried to go back to the old "restricted" policy files(local_policy.jar, US_export_policy.jar), I am not getting any errors any more. This does not make sense to me,any explanation to help resolve this mystery is appreciated.